# file upload using phpSmug

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I am working on an app that will upload images to my smugmug account. I am using phpSmug 3.4 and the following code:

```
require_once( "phpSmug.php" );



    try {
        //assign Variable to smugmug
        $f = new phpSmug("APIKey=*****************", "AppName=Test/1.0");
        // Login Anonymously
        $f->login();    




            $f->images_upload("AlbumID=2282300", "File=TestPic.jpg");



    }
    catch ( Exception $e ) {
        echo "{$e->getMessage()} (Error Code: {$e->getCode()})";
    }
```

?>

but I get back: 
      SmugMug API Error for method image_upload: missing required parameter (Error Code: 22)

Do I have to use Oauth to upload? or can it be done anonymously? or is my syntax wrong?

any help is appreciated... Thanks

I also asked the question on the smugmug stack exchange so
if this is not appropriate here, I apologize..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of phpSmug, I can tell you your problem and solution is simple: you can't upload images to Smugmug anonymously. You need to login using one of the identifying authentication methods supported by SmugMug and implemented in phpSmug.

Comment: Thanks,you are correct. I am using email/pass method, and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

My fault...was not working from my localhost, works fine on server